# Modular way to import object instances

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to define object instances in javascript files, like this.

Below's content is in a file `serviceKnex.js`.

```
import Knex from 'knex'

var knex = Knex({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  },
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'migrations'
  }
})

export default knex
```

Then be able to `import` `serviceKnex.js` and use it directly in a function like this.

```
import serviceKnex from '../serviceKnex'

export async function createItem () {
  return serviceKnex('table')
    .insert({'hello', 'world'})
}
```

However, I'd like to make the above code a npm module, that can ideally receive `serviceKnex` the object as an argument. I still want a consumer of this function to be able to alter which `knex` object instance they are using.

Is there any way to allow a simple modular, swappable interface for importing and using global object instances?

I'm trying to prevent myself from writing functions like this, that pass in the `knex` object.

```
export async function createItem (knex) {
  return knex('table')
    .insert({'hello', 'world'})
}
```

Comment: If your service is stateless then I imagine it would need to know the context by passing knex. Otherwise you'l need your singleton service to hold a reference to this knex object.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a wrapper class which takes `serviceKnex` as an argument in the constructor, and additionally provides a `setKnex()` method.

Example:

```
export default class DatabaseClass {
    constructor(serviceKnex) {
        this.serviceKnex = serviceKnex;
    }

    setKnex(knexService) {
        this.serviceKnex = serviceKnex;
    }

    async createItem() {
        return this.serviceKnex('table')
            .insert({'hello', 'world'});
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
import serviceKnex from '../serviceKnex';
import DatabaseClass from 'database-class';

var dbObject = new DatabaseClass(knexService);
dbObject.createItem();
```

If you don't want to use classes you can add a setter function in the NPM module code which modifies the global variable, but I personally prefer the wrapper class approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered prototypical inheritance? Similar to how jQuery is built, something along the lines of:

```
function serviceKnex (knexInstance) {
  return new init(knexInstance)
}

function init (knexInstance) {
  this.instance = knexInstance
  return this
}

init.prototype = {
  createItem () {
    return this.instance('table').insert({'hello', 'world'})
  }
}

export default serviceKnex
```

Then your users would be able to work with different instances.

```
import Knex from 'knex'
import serviceKnex from 'serviceKnex'

const knexOne = Knex({})
const knexTwo = Knex({})

const serviceKnexOne = serviceKnex(knexOne)
const serviceKnexTwo = serviceKnex(knexTwo)

serviceKnexOne.createItem()
serviceKnexTwo.createItem()
```

EDIT: Or with ES6 classes as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602357/1666547) points out.